# Cloudformation template: Cloudfront DomainName WebsiteURL returns Error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudfront

i have created a Cloudformation template for a S3 static site deployment.

In the cloudfront part the domain name must be specified. First I created the template like this and tried it out:

```json
...
"DomainName": {
  "Fn::GetAtt": [
    "S3BucketRoot",
    "DomainName"
  ]
},
...
```

So everything was put on so far correctly. Only the one the Origin domain was not taken correctly. The `Amazon S3 bucket` Origin domain name was returned and not the `Amazon S3 bucket configured as a website`. This caused requests to the domain to not load correctly.

I then manually entered the `Amazon S3 bucket configured as a website` Origin domain name in cloudfront.
After this worked correctly I wanted to change it in the template and so I adjusted it:

```json
...
"DomainName": {
  "Fn::GetAtt": [
    "S3BucketRoot",
    "WebsiteURL"
  ]
},
...
```

When updating the stack I now get the error that there must not be a colon in the domain name. This comes from the `http://...`

So my question now is, how can i either get the right DomainName or how can i remove the `http://` from the WebsiteURL?

My S3 configuration looks like this:

```json
"S3BucketRoot": {
      "Type": "AWS::S3::Bucket",
      "DeletionPolicy": "Delete",
      "Properties": {
        "AccessControl": "PublicRead",
        "BucketName": {
          "Fn::Sub": "${AWS::StackName}-root"
        },
        "WebsiteConfiguration": {
          "ErrorDocument": "404.html",
          "IndexDocument": "index.html"
        }
      }
    },
```

Edit:
[Origin Domain Name Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/distribution-web-values-specify.html#DownloadDistValuesDomainName)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it with a little hack

```json
...
"DomainName": {
  "Fn::Select": [
    "1",
    {
      "Fn::Split": [
        "http://",
        {
          "Fn::GetAtt": [
            "S3BucketRoot",
            "WebsiteURL"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
},
...
```

If someone finds a better way, pleas let me know. For now, this works.

[Resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference.html)

Answer (score 0):

Don't make it to complicated

```
!Sub ${S3BucketRoot}.s3-website-${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com
```